Poem ascribed to Anna Akhmatova (Spanish required)
In some Spanish language social media posts and websites the following poem is attributed to Anna Akhmatova:

Mi vida ha transcurrido en algún sitio/
del que yo estaba ausente./
¡Cuántas veces se levantó el telón/
y la escena vacía/
en vano ha esperado por mí!/
¡Cuántas veces/
tendió el amor los brazos/
hacia mi cuerpo trémulo/
y abrazó solo arena,/
una mujer sin nombre,/
mientras yo sonreía en otra parte!/
A mis mejores amigos/
los perdí en algún recodo del camino/
antes de haberlos encontrado./
Conozco palmo a palmo una ciudad/
y nunca he estado en ella./
Me han conmovido hasta las lágrimas/
mares que nunca he visto,/
versos que nunca he escrito,/
un rostro en el espejo,/
que era el rostro de mi madre/
y el de la hija que no tuve/
y el de una desconocida/
que me miraba con extraño amor,/
pero nunca era el mío./
Alguien que se llevó mis risas,/
me ha dejado sus lágrimas./
¿De quién son estas lágrimas,/
de quién este dolor/
que me traspasa un pecho que no es mío?/
Me han robado mi vida,/
no lloréis en mi tumba. En ella yace,/
bajo mi nombre, una desconocida./

I would like to have the original Russian. However I have tried to paraphrase in English and looked for it in the English translations of her poems but I can’t find any trace of it. The Spanish translator does not seem to indicate where is it taken from. Maybe someone by chance expert in Akhmatova that reads Spanish can help me?

I believe this is a reasonably well-known poem by Akhmatova, known by its first line "This cruel age has deflected me...". The first and last lines of the Spanish text that the OP quotes can be translated:

How many times has the curtain risen   and the empty scene waited
in vain for me!  


My love, do not cry at my grave.   There
lies, under my name, a stranger.  

Comparing this with an English translation of the poem from the collection Poems of Akhmatova (1973) by Stanley Kunitz and Max Hayward:

How many spectacles I’ve missed:   the curtain rising without me,
 and falling too. 


The grave I go to will not be my own.   But if I
could step outside myself   and contemplate the person that I am,
 I should know at last what envy is.  

The Spanish translation is rather free, but it tells the same story and uses the same imagery (a curtain rising, a familiar city, a usurper, a grave). The Russian text of the poem is also available at this page.

That’s a dramatically free translation of the original poem, but seems likely.

My strategy for trying to find an original quote from a translation is to look for some unusual word or words in the translation. “Curtain” (telón) seems to be a good choice and as near as I can tell, there are only a handful of Akhmatova poems which use the word curtain in them.

Wow, impressive. Super thanks.

El placer es mío @DanielCastro
